# How to add and delete list items with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a project to create list items. If I type a word in the input and then press the add button, you need to add the word to the list. The problem is that the previously typed word remains in the input. I want the input to be blank after pressing the add button.
The other problem is that I want to put an icon next to each new list item that is created, which, when pressed, deletes the current row. I don't know how to do this.
For example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XImCk.png)

So far I have done the task with html, css and jQuery:

```
<main>

    <h1 id="title">My list</h1>
    <div id="addList">

        <input type="text" id="input">
        <button id="addBtn">add</button>

    </div>

    <ul>

    </ul>

</main>


<style>
    * {
        font-family: Arial;

    }

    body {
        background: rgb(79, 179, 236);
    }

    main {
        width: 450px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
        border: solid 1px rgb(24, 165, 231);
        background: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /*Title*/
    #title {
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* input and button*/
    #addList {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #input {
        border: solid 1px rgb(24, 165, 231);
    }

    #addBtn {
        border: none;
        background: rgb(24, 165, 231);
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    #addBtn:hover {
        background: rgb(61, 163, 211);
        color: white;
    }

    #input,
    #addBtn {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    /* List*/

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#addBtn').click(function () {
        if ($('#input').val()) {
            $("ul").append(`<li> ${$('#input').val()}</li>`);
        }

        else {
            alert('empty input!')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is that what you want with icon? if not, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#addBtn').click(function () {
        if ($('#input').val()) {
            $("ul").append(`<li>${$('#input').val()}<button id="det" onclick="dete(this);"><i class="trash fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></li>`);
            $("input").val("");
        }

        else {
            alert('empty input!')
        }
    });
    
function dete(e){
e.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```css
* {
        font-family: Arial;

    }

    body {
        background: rgb(79, 179, 236);
    }

    main {
        width: 450px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
        border: solid 1px rgb(24, 165, 231);
        background: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /*Title*/
    #title {
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* input and button*/
    #addList {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #input {
        border: solid 1px rgb(24, 165, 231);
    }

    #addBtn {
        border: none;
        background: rgb(24, 165, 231);
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    #addBtn:hover {
        background: rgb(61, 163, 211);
        color: white;
    }

    #input,
    #addBtn {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    /* List*/

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
.trash{
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:36px !important;
color:red;
}
.style{
padding-right: 40px;
}
#det{
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
border: none;
background: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<main>

    <h1 id="title">My list</h1>
    <div id="addList">

        <input type="text" id="input">
        <button id="addBtn">add</button>

    </div>

    <ul class="style">

    </ul>

</main>
```

Try This!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want.

```js
    $('#addBtn').click(function () {
        if ($('#input').val()) {
            $("ul").append(`<li> ${$('#input').val()}</li>`);
            $("input").val("");
        }

        else {
            alert('empty input!')
        }
    });
</script>
```

```css
* {
        font-family: Arial;

    }

    body {
        background: rgb(79, 179, 236);
    }

    main {
        width: 450px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
        border: solid 1px rgb(24, 165, 231);
        background: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /*Title*/
    #title {
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* input and button*/
    #addList {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #input {
        border: solid 1px rgb(24, 165, 231);
    }

    #addBtn {
        border: none;
        background: rgb(24, 165, 231);
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    #addBtn:hover {
        background: rgb(61, 163, 211);
        color: white;
    }

    #input,
    #addBtn {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    /* List*/

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>

    <h1 id="title">My list</h1>
    <div id="addList">

        <input type="text" id="input">
        <button id="addBtn">add</button>

    </div>

    <ul>

    </ul>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want including icons.

```js
$('#addBtn').click(function () {
        if ($('#input').val()) {
            $("ul").append(`<li data-value="2"> ${$('#input').val()} <i id='icon-minus' class="fa fa-heart"></i></li>`);
            $("input").val("");
        }

        else {
            alert('empty input!')
        }
    });
   
   $(document).ready(function()
{
        $(document).on('click','#icon-minus',
        function() 
        {
            var $list =  $("#servelist"),
                listValue = $(this).parent().data('value');
            $list.find('li[data-value="' + listValue + '"]').slideUp("fast", function() 
            {
              $(this).remove();
            });            
        });
});

   
</script>
```

```css
* {
        font-family: Arial;

    }

    body {
        background: rgb(79, 179, 236);
    }

    main {
        width: 450px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
        border: solid 1px rgb(24, 165, 231);
        background: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /*Title*/
    #title {
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* input and button*/
    #addList {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #input {
        border: solid 1px rgb(24, 165, 231);
    }

    #addBtn {
        border: none;
        background: rgb(24, 165, 231);
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    #addBtn:hover {
        background: rgb(61, 163, 211);
        color: white;
    }

    #input,
    #addBtn {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    /* List*/

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>

    <h1 id="title">My list</h1>
    <div id="addList">

        <input type="text" id="input">
        <button id="addBtn">add</button>

    </div>

    <ul id="servelist">

    </ul>

</main>
```